# Language Hotkeys removed by itself in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys, input-languages

I have four keyboards and I have defined Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2 and Ctrl+3 ... hot-keys for them. The problem is that either all of the hot-keys or the first one is removed regularly. For example every time the computer goes to sleep (or even locked) all of them are removed.

I even tried other hot-keys (Ctrl+Shift+1, ... Ctrl+Shift+4) or (Alt+Shift+1, ... Alt+Shift+4) and the problem still exist.

If I assign a transition key (Left Shift+Alt) it will work but that's not that useful when you have more than 2 keyboards and you want to regularly change the keyboard.

It appears that the problem has existed in Windows 8 too (and has something to do with welcome screen) but the solution I found does not work on Windows 10 (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/custom-hotkeys-to-change-input-language-disappear/66d1d89d-e5dc-41e1-a8b3-48d596ab8e11).

Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

Comment: I myself have that problem. But no idea how to solve it. Various 'fixes' found on the internet did not help for me...

Comment: I found several similar items on windows "Feedback Hub": [1](https://aka.ms/Gdizvi), [2](https://aka.ms/Qolwvc), [3](https://aka.ms/X32sf0), [4](https://aka.ms/T5stiy), [5](https://aka.ms/Pym0i3) - consider up-voting them - there's a tiny chance that this might help.

Comment: Ran into same problem. Windows 10 20h2. I even cannot change hotkeys - when press Apply - they are reseted to ctrl+1 and ctrl+2 immediately. I restarted PC in safe mode: windows+R - msconfig - Boot - tick Safe boot, restart. In this mode mode both hotkeys are None. It seems they are set by some driver in normal mode indeed. I changed them to some useless combination for me like ctrl+shift+8 and ctrl+shift+9, restarted again in safe mode. Binds are saved. Then changed them to None. Restarted back to usual mode. And binds stopped reseting by themselves.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I finally found the solution and I am posting, in case someone else has the problem.

1- Define your hot-keys.

2- Search and find the "region" settings palette and go to administrative tab.

[image: region-administrative tab]

Now go to "Copy Settings" section.

[image: copy settings]

Select both tick boxes below the window and press ok.

In my case this applied the settings in a way that they are no more removed.

Edit: In case you cannot find the language Hot-key definition in windows 10, in the latest editions, it is here:

[image]

Comment: That's the solution found in the link you have posted in your question isn't it?

Comment: The solution was for windows 8. It is the same but with a bit difference for windows 10. In windows 10, the settings are in a different place than the one mentioned in that link (for windows 8).

Comment: Any solution for users without administrative rights?

Comment: It looks like the issue is still there. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. It specially after additional updates - you have to re-set all the hotkeys again, but no warranty that they will work.

Comment: What to do if there are two users and both of them have different hotkeys?

Comment: Stunning hoe many threads about this can be found on Microsoft's own forum and yet Microsoft does nothing to fix it. E.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-forgets-language-switching-key/fc331d98-e942-4143-b596-0ef16586e406, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/400a7b3b-904a-47a8-9e6d-c958c7328b7e/windows-10-keeps-forgetting-language-bar-hot-keys?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: Yes, copying settings from current user to default user works. But I could do this via RegEdit only.
I copied two entries (for two custom keys) from
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-(MYUSER-ID)-1001\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys\00000100] and 00000101
to
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys]
...

Comment: 4 years later Windows 10 May 2020 update has just broken the language hotkeys for me again. But never mind, now I have an asterisk in Notepad's title bar for unsaved changes, wow!

Comment: Thank you! It works for me for Win10 Pro(v1909)(10.0.18363 Build 18363). {Settings -> Device -> Typing -> Advanced keyboard settings -> Input language hot keys} for the first one; {Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> Additional data, time & region settings -> (this will pop up control panel with Region and click the Region) -> Administrative Tab -> Copy settings -> Check-marked the two as the above solution said} for the second one. Then, restart PC. My hot keys work now.

Comment: Autumn update in 2020 and keys are gone again. But never mind, now I have... well, what I have instead?

Comment: 2022 and the workaround doesn't help anymore...

Comment: still works for me. it's incredible that this is needed at all though