# Layout switching hotkeys are lost in WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I have 3 languages tied to Left <kbd>Alt+Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd>. They are reset to 'None' after sleep every couple of days.

Why is this? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

From an answer I made [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1182822/how-can-one-disable-automatic-re-adding-of-an-unwanted-keyboard-layout-in-window/1183836#1183836)

> If you go to: Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Language >
>   Advanced settings
>
> You will see an option to override default input method. You can set
>   this to your wanted keyboard setting.
>
> If you click on Change language bar hot keys (see image bottom) you
>   can change the ALT+SHIFT or CTRL+SHIFT hotkeys. A button in the
>   Advanced tab will say Change key sequence. From there you can choose
>   the desired hotkey.

If this doesn't save then there might be something wrong in the regkeys. Or windows just doesn't save your settings properly. In that case once you've set your hotkeys properly try some steps from this answer: [Language Hotkeys removed by itself in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1031736/language-hotkeys-removed-by-itself-in-windows-10)

Comment: I wonder why everybody thinks that it is an issue to make the hotkeys when they understand the real issue? Probably, they need to refer their posts to advance them for rating.

Comment: @valentin ?? You explained your problem. Problem is the hotkeys are reset after a few days in sleep mode. I know you know how to make the hotkeys properly but other people might not. So they can combine the 2 answers and still solve the problem easily.